# HTML in emails not rendering

Tags: meteor

I use the meteor-ssr package to render email templates serverside and send them

Template:

```
Hello

A request to change your payment account was sent. If this was not you, your account may be compromised and you should reset your password immediately.

New account: {{pending.email}}

Click the link below to confirm the change.
<a href="{{id}}">{{id}}</a>
```

And server

```
sendPaymentChangeToken: function() {
      SSR.compileTemplate('paymentChangeEmail', Assets.getText('paymentChange.html'));
      var user   = Meteor.user();
      var email  = user.emails[0].address;
      var token  = user.payment.token;

      var html = SSR.render("paymentChangeEmail", token);
      Email.send({
        from: 'Tabler <no-reply@tabler.com>',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Payment Confirmation',
        text: html
      });
    }
```

Problem is the link tag i rendered as

```
 <a href="27d8bdca14be4522abdb5fddf9f86c9f8ba29a3500660">27d8bdca14be4522abdb5fddf9f86c9f8ba29a3500660</a>
```

Instead of actually providing a link

Any help is much appreciate

Comment: In `Email.send` use `html` instead of `text`. Text is meant if you don't want it to be parsed out as html.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning your string of HTML to [the `text` property instead of the `html` property](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email).

Don't send pure HTML emails though, that's a good flat for spam filters. Send a multipart email with equivalent HTML and plain text parts. Hopefully the email package will do The Right Thing if you assign values to both `html` and `text`.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by pure HTML. Is it the ratio of text wrapped in HTML elements compared to those not?

Comment: https://litmus.com/blog/reach-more-people-and-improve-your-spam-score-why-multi-part-email-is-important

Answer (score 1):

You need to change text o html like akshat says

```
 Email.send({
        from: 'Tabler <no-reply@tabler.com>',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Payment Confirmation',
        text: html
      });
```

To

```
 Email.send({
        from: 'Tabler <no-reply@tabler.com>',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Payment Confirmation',
        html : html
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that token in sendPaymentChangeToken is being mapped to {{id}} in your SSR template, it looks like you forgot to include the server URL.

Try:

```
var token = Meteor.absoluteUrl() + user.payment.token;
```